# iPhone doesn’t support any of architectures. (Unsupported Architectures)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Recently I have purchased iPhone XS (iOS 12) and since I build my app on iPhone 6S I get an error when I try to run the app I'm developing.

### Error:

> User’s iPhone doesn’t support any of appname.app’s
> architectures. You can add User’s iPhone’s arm64e
> architecture to appname.app’s Architectures build setting.

I try to add **arm64e** as mentioned above to **Project>Build Settings>Valid Architectures**, but still same error. Also to mention that Architectures is **Standard architectures - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)**.

What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve this? I know this is due to the A12 chip as I read through the Web, but no one suggests a fix.

[image]

Comment: Why are you setting iOS 11.4 for Base SDK?

Comment: @ElTomato The iOS 11.4 Base SDK is what it supported at Xcode 9.4.1. to get the iOS 12 it must be updated to Xcode 10.0. It's solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Upgrade to Xcode 10.0

The problem can be solved by simply upgrading your Xcode to 10.0.

Comment: Is there any solution in Xcode 9?
(Framework developers sometimes need to stick to the old environment...)

Comment: @inexcii not that I'm aware of. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

## **Upgrade to Xcode 10.1**

You can find it [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/)